# Подсчёт количества значений, удовлетворяющих условию

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется такой DataFrame:

```
    X0  X1  X2  X3
0   3,7465759356    3,9929524521    3,7290598962    3,9416020757
1   2,9405285627    3,0125809054    2,9256071617    3,0370817644
2   2,3907682395    2,4959628959    2,4203315485    2,5123345286
3   2,667769289     2,8169243037    2,7067755525    2,819941095
4   3,5174069746    3,6947015318    3,6031473706    3,7293446909
5   3,4971753456    3,6318386869    3,6087157237    3,7127634955
6   3,2799369789    3,4026277202    3,3287014594    3,4729836704
7   2,4688361461    2,5931613428    2,5884721857    2,654343142
8   4,9480920436    5,2618326433    4,8367411213    5,200340321
9   2,5839918711    2,6564664314    2,6567353365    2,7084738201
10  3,0235179227    3,1846965709    3,1420435571    3,226176654
11  3,0255560454    3,1951865571    3,0625562893    3,2035708459
12  2,7435363038    2,903039071     2,8066417483    2,8831451723
13  3,0989225389    3,2759484764    3,1365404027    3,2829481328
14  2,8791101525    3,022431196     2,9171600354    3,0358254158
15  2,7738942062    2,9198893522    2,8638428564    2,9505456377
16  2,9773768478    3,1439135641    3,0404570931    3,1432559901
17  3,797767158     3,9607999032    3,8791070242    3,996404042
18  3,2645562122    3,4412127816    3,3172450423    3,4297893267
19  3,3094225229    3,466520235     3,3665861539    3,4687251807
20  3,2254435518    3,3669423406    3,277272531     3,364696979
21  2,8072222974    2,9509018409    2,8844643202    2,9489983818
22  2,7158702035    2,8557259219    2,7866183624    2,8580161063
23  3,8817612736    4,0851040662    3,9423929322    4,0888494407
24  3,728452702     3,8862195997    3,8077051346    3,855946951
```

Как подсчитать количество значений в каждой строке, удовлетворяющих условию? Например, если условие - число больше трёх, то результат такой:

```
4
2
0
0
4
4
4
0
4
0 и т.д.
```

UPD. Приведённый DataFrame получен путём длинного расчёта. Не вижу смысла приводить здесь весь расчёт. Помогающим предлагаю воспользоваться таким DataFrame:

```
F = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(15, 4), columns=['X0', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3'])
```

Comment: Это файл какой разметки?

Comment: @KitScribe, файл? Это [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html).

Comment: Я забыл как называется данный формат разметки (tsv). Я понимаю, что вы делаете DataFrame. Но не в скрипт же мне вписывать всё. Гораздо лучше же из файла данные читать и делать df

Comment: @KitScribe, обновил вопрос.

Comment: @KitScribe, это вывод (output) DataFrame на экран. Если хотите его прочитать - воспользуйтесь [pd.read_clipboard(decimal=',')](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего - вот так:

```
In [10]: df.gt(3).sum(axis=1)
Out[10]:
0     4
1     2
2     0
3     0
4     4
5     4
6     4
7     0
8     4
9     0
10    4
11    4
12    0
13    4
14    2
15    0
16    3
17    4
18    4
19    4
20    4
21    0
22    0
23    4
24    4
dtype: int64
```

**Пояснение** - для краткости вывода я все операции буду делать только для первых пяти строк (`df.head()`):

```
In [14]: df.head()
Out[14]:
         X0        X1        X2        X3
0  3.746576  3.992952  3.729060  3.941602
1  2.940529  3.012581  2.925607  3.037082
2  2.390768  2.495963  2.420332  2.512335
3  2.667769  2.816924  2.706776  2.819941
4  3.517407  3.694702  3.603147  3.729345

In [15]: df.head().gt(3)
Out[15]:
      X0     X1     X2     X3
0   True   True   True   True
1  False   True  False   True
2  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False
4   True   True   True   True
```

Т.к. `True == 1`, а `False == 0`, то просуммировав значения (True, False, ...) по строкам (`.sum(axis=)`), получим к-во элементов в строке, удовлетворяющих условию

```
In [16]: df.head().gt(3).sum(axis=1)
Out[16]:
0    4
1    2
2    0
3    0
4    4
dtype: int64
```

для более сложных условий:

```
In [13]: ((df > 2) & (df < 3)).sum(1)
Out[13]:
0     0
1     2
2     4
3     4
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     4
8     0
9     4
10    0
11    0
12    4
13    0
14    2
15    4
16    1
17    0
18    0
19    0
20    0
21    4
22    4
23    0
24    0
dtype: int64
```